# What is the meaning of "a roach in the rushes"?

Tags: meaning

In George R.R. Martin's *A Game of Thrones*,

> I would have given a hundred silver stags to have been *a roach in the rushes* when he learned that Lord Beric was off to behead his brother.

what does *a roach in the rushes* mean?

Comment: sounds like "fly on the wall" could easily be substituted.

Comment: Too Localised - it's a made-up expression used by one author, on just [two occasions in a series of books](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22a+roach+in+the+rushes%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1)

Answer (score 9):

We would say "I would love to have been a fly on the wall in that meeting" to mean we would love to have been able to eavesdrop. "A roach in the rushes" is Martin's way of making up an idiom for "eavesdropping" to use in his fanciful world — making it up so that it didn't sound like an ordinary English cliché.

Comment: I don't know the context - is there any possibility that the setting is aquatic, and *roach* is a fish?

Comment: @StoneyB: No. The rushes are the kind they used to spread in dining halls, which would acquire a litter of table scraps (and hence roaches) and would be swept up and replaced periodically.

Comment: Hokey-dokey - the first thing I thought of when I saw the quote was Sword in the Stone.

Answer (score 4):

Rushes were often used as floor covering in mediaeval halls, being cheap, easily gathered, and mildly fragrant.

> 1903    *Trans. Shropsh. Archaeol. & Nat. Hist. Soc. 3 288*  Floors were sanded, or strewn with rushes, and the test of a house was not ‘Were the carpets well shaken?’ but, ‘Were the rushes often changed?’

(taken nearly at random from the OED)

So Martin probably just needed an archaic-sounding equivalent for 'fly on the wall'; *Rushes* as a dried floor covering fits nicely with his background, and forms a nice alliterative phrase.

As a point of interest, (barely relevant to the answer)  *roach* for cockroach is American: the eighteenth-century equivalent (and so presumably the mediaeval term) was *blackbeetle*.

Comment: Since the quote is about Shropshire, wouldn't the more likely phrase have been 'blackbeetle in the rushes' (since there're not many medieval halls in the US)?

Comment: @Mitch: what does 'more likely' mean? As a guess at what a mediaeval Shropshireman would have said, yes (ignoring the changes in the language, dialects, and so forth.)  As a striking alliterative phrase for a fictional pseudo-mediaeval nobleman (as I understand it: I haven't read *Game of Thrones*),  probably not.

Comment: What I meant was, if 'roach' is a mostly American term, then 'roach in the rushes' on its face would be anachronistic ( an American wouldn't have mush chance to see consider a roach among rushes on the floor of a medieval castle). Or was 'roach' used as an Americanism by BrE speakers at the time of that quote? Oh...hold on..you're not claiming that 'roach in the rushes' was ever spoken by non-Americans, right? So what are you saying then?

Comment: I think it's inconceivable Martin meant *cockroaches*. As you say yourself, *roach = cockroach* is American (and far more recent than "medieval", imho). And as @Robusto says, the whole point of the expression is that it's made up for the specific context - it would be self-defeating if it seemed to allude to a modern-day pest normally associated with central-heated houses.

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, it's a more fanciful replacement for the idiom "a fly on the wall."

However, a [roach](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/roach) is actually "a small freshwater fish in the carp family", and [rushes](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/rush#English) are "any of several stiff aquatic or marsh plants", so the mental image invoked is intended to be that of a meeting happening whilst fishing (or similar lake-based activity) and a small fish has gotten close enough to hear the conversation, remaining unnoticed due to the plant life growing in the water.

<sub>(Credit to JWPat7 for initially mentioning that a roach is also a fish, and to StoneyB for bringing it up again and inspiring me to post.)</sub>

Comment: I assumed *roach=fish* was common knowledge - but Robusto doesn't explicitly say that, which perhaps explains why some people were tempted to ascribe the modern American *roach=insect* meaning. I still think the question should be closed, but at least this is the full & correct answer!

Answer (score 0):

In this context it means "to be present" or "witness the facts".